# TortoiseSVN: Merging two ancestrally unrelated branches

Tags: svn, version-control, merge, tortoisesvn, svn-merge

I am trying to merge a branch into the trunk. They have no common ancestor.

The branch was created sometime in the past with a simple Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V of the trunk, a practice which, of course, "broke" any future merge operation between the two, as they are not ancestrally related.

I want to *replace* the trunk with the branch. I do not care about the commit history in the trunk -- it can be ignored and/or erased, if need be. I do care about the commit history in the branch -- it must be available in the "new" trunk.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to simply clear the trunk directory and move the content of the branch into the trunk directory? For deleting the content use `svn delete` and for moving the content of the branch use `svn move`. `svn move´ will preserve your history.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWaHI.png)

You can use the "Mark as resolved" option to clear the conflict. After that you can merge without the ancestries issues.

Comment: It looks like you haven't completed your answer. Please edit it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).